# Is there way to have more nextElementSibling s in line?

Tags: javascript

I need to point to exactly fourth nextElementSibling, is there any simplified way to do that?

```
var x = document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
```

Comment: You could create a small function called `getNthSibling(element, n)` (for example) which would loop over the given element.

Comment: Not really. You could do it in a loop, if you think that’s any nicer. Or you could get all the children of the parent and select elements by index (but then you would need to figure out which index your actual activeElement has in there first of all.)

Comment: Well, it is possible to avoid n-fold repetition with built-in APIs: `var x = ((range) => (range.setStartBefore(document.activeElement), range.setEndAfter(document.activeElement.parentElement.lastElementChild), range.cloneContents().children[4]))(new Range());`. The `4` in there is equivalent to 4 `.nextElementSibling`s.